# I am trying to store node pointers in a vector and I am having a heap-use-after-free error

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, heap-memory

I am solving the Leetcode problem [206. Reverse Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/description/):

> Given the `head` of a singly linked list, reverse the list, and return *the reversed list*.

Here is my code.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
        vector<ListNode*> addrs;
        ListNode* cur=head;
        if(cur==NULL||cur->next==NULL) return cur;

        // storing all addrs in sequence
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            addrs.push_back(cur);
            cur=cur->next;
        }
        // reversing process
        for(int i=addrs.size()-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            addrs[i]->next=addrs[i-1];
        }
        return addrs[addrs.size()-1];
    }
};
```

When I test the code at LeetCode, I get this error:

> ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free

I am guessing that the error is related to the vector. However I don't get the exact reason why I have this error. Can someone help me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error does not occur in your code, but in the cleanup code that the LeetCode platform executes *after* having called your function.

The deeper *cause* is that your function does not set the `next` member of the original head node. This node has become the tail and so its `next` member should be updated to `nullptr`, which you forgot to do. By consequence your rewired linked list has no end. It has a cycle between its last two nodes.

And so when LeetCode wants to free up the memory used by your linked list -- not expecting it to have a cycle -- it will visit a node for a second time and try to free it *again*: this triggers the exception.

The solution is simple. Add this code just before the final `return` statement:

```
addrs[0]->next = nullptr;
```

Note that you should use `nullptr` in your code instead of `NULL`.

Also, a remaining challenge is to solve this exercise without O(n) auxiliary memory, i.e. without the vector. It is possible to do with just a few pointer variables. Maybe you want to try that...

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation!! I've also solved the remaining challenge you mentioned. Thanks (: